# How to filter logs by user using pgFouine?

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

I'm using [pgFouine](http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/index.html) as log analyser for my postgreSQL database. Log are stored via syslog.
I don't want to see logs from every db user but just the one of my app.

How to do that? Filter must apply on syslog or on pgFouine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgFouine can filter on this *if* you log the right information.

http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/tutorial.html